# Metrics not getting logged to Run history-azure machine learning

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an azure-ML pipeline using pythonscriptstep method. I am able to see the metrics getting logged to individual steps as in the figure below.
[image]

But I am not able to see the metrics (**I logged the input_shape** )getting logged to the *Run History report* when I open the experiment.

[image]

Any help is appreciated please.

Comment: Solved the by logging the metrics to the parent run.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Priya's answer and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-run-parent). It is solved by logging to the parent run like so:

```py
mse = mean_squared_error(estimator.predict(data), target)
run = Run.get_context()
run.parent.log("mse", mse)
```